# How to remove individual Unity Webapps' items from message indicator?

Tags: unity, indicator, webapps

In first days of trying Ubuntu 12.10 I installed a bunch of unity webapps like Launchpad, Twitter, Facebook, LinkdIn, etc.

Recently I found some of them useless and removed the related "unity-webapps-*" packages. They no longer appear in the Launcher and Every time I visit the main website in firefox, they offer to install the unity webapp for that specific website as well.

But the problem is the items for them (LinkedIn, Twitter and Facebook) are placed in the message indicator yet after Thunderbird and Of course they don't indicate anything.

How can I completely remove the webapps items from unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to *com > canonical > unity > webapps* in "dconf Editor" and remove the items from "**allowed-domains**" section and then replace unity
[image]